# Method overload resolution using dynamic argument

Tags: c#, dynamic, overloading, overload-resolution

This may have been answered before. I see many "dynamic method overload resolution" questions, but none that deal specifically with passing a `dynamic` argument. In the following code, in `Test`, the last call to `M` cannot be resolved (**it doesn't compile**). The error is: *the call is ambiguous between [the first two overloads of `M`]*.

```
static void M(Func<int> f) { }
static void M(Func<string> f) { }
static void M(Func<dynamic> f) { }

static dynamic DynamicObject() {
    return new object();
}

static void Test() {
    M(() => 0);
    M(() => "");
    M(() => DynamicObject()); //doesn't compile
}
```

1. Why, since the type isn't statically known, does it not resolve to the overload accepting `dynamic`?
2. Is it even possible for an overloaded method to use `dynamic`?
3. What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a generic here?  It would still be ambiguous as is (bear in mind a dynamic can be A and can be B, how does the compiler know which to call?).  But if you wanted I think you could change the methods to `static void M<T>(Func<DataTime, T> f) where T : A` and `static void M<T>(Func<DataTime, T> f) where T : B` and I think that would allow the overloading? - Certainly all of the method calls in `Test` should be ok?

Comment: The example is contrived, but the one part that accurately reflects my dilemma is passing `dynamic` to an overloaded method. How is that best resolved?

Comment: As above - don't.  How can you overload an object that can be anything?

Comment: @Smudge: of course you can have an overload accepting `object`. See Tigran's working example.

Comment: Don't do that! Use a generic instead!

Comment: @Daniel - my mistake, poor choice of wording.  "How can you overload an 'entity that can be a class/struct/value/anything until a target type is inferred'(?)"

Comment: @Smudge: By choosing the method that accepts a class/struct/value/anything??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is type inference. The compiler is trying to find out which overload to use based on the argument, but it's also trying to find out what the type of the argument is based on the chosen overload. In the case of `M(() => DynamicObject())`, the process goes something like this:

1. The argument to the method is a lambda with zero parameters. This gives us all three overloads as possibilities.
2. The body of the lambda returns `dynamic`. Because there is an implicit conversion from `dynamic` to any other type, we now know all three overloads are good.
3. Try choosing the best overload. In most cases, “best” means the most derived type. Because both `int` and `string` derive from `object`, the overloads with `int` and `string` are considered best.
4. We now have two “best” overloads, which means the compiler can't actually choose one of them. The compilation fails.

Now, regarding possible solutions to your problem:

1. Make the type of the lambda explicit, either using cast or typed local variable:

   ```
   M((Func<dynamic>)(() => DynamicObject()));
   ```

   or

   ```
   Func<dynamic> f = () => DynamicObject();
   M(f);
   ```
2. Rename the dynamic overload to something like `DynamicM`. This way, you don't have to deal with overload resolution.
3. This one feels somewhat wrong to me: make sure the `dynamic` overload is the only one that fits, by casting to `object`:

   ```
   M(() => (object)DynamicObject())
   ```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of `Func` being contravariant. I think `dynamic`/`object` being in the contravariant position is the source of the problem. I'm still wondering why it didn't include the `dynamic` overload in the list of possible matches.

Comment: @Daniel, this is not about contravariance. The same thing would happen if `Func` wasn't contravariant. And the compiler did include the `dynamic` overload in the first pass, but it didn't include it among one of the “best” matches.

Comment: Gotcha. You're right about it picking the most specific overload. I changed the first overload to accept `Func<A>` and the second `Func<B>` (`B` derives from `A`) and it resolved to the second one. Strange, but true.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition in MSDN:

[dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However,
>   operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved
>   or type checked by the compiler. The compiler packages together
>   information about the operation, and that information is later used to
>   evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, variables
>   of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore,
>   type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time

So dynamic doesn't exist when you compile, cause it needs to convert it into *destination* *type*, and that's why is not able to resolve it. What is destination type ?

In fact if you do something like this:

```
static void M(Func<int> f) { }
static void M(Func<string> f) { }
static void M(Func<object> f) { } // could be also declared like dynamic here, works by the way

static object DynamicObject()
{
    return new object();
}

static void Test()
{
    M(() => 0);
    M(() => "");
    M(() => DynamicObject());
}
```

It perfectly works as you want, as `object` is present like a type already at compile time, in difference of `dynamic` type which have to be *converted*.

Comment: Your example shows precisely why I thought it _would_ work, given that `dynamic` is just `object`. Is there any way for overload resolution to work with `dynamic`?

Comment: No:) dynamic is not an object, it have to be converted in some type at compile time, but in this case it's not possible to understand which type is have to be its destination...

Comment: OK, so back to my original question: is there any way to have an overload that accepts `dynamic`, or will it never resolve?

Comment: IMHO, there is no possibility, also I never seen overloading on dynamic types. Would be curiouse to see other posts.

Comment: Aren't you describing the exact functionality that generics provide?  You seem to be hung up on the word `dynamic` but that is *not* the word your after?

Comment: The meaning of use generics is provide template oriented architecture but maintain type safity, in case of dynamic, you don't have type safity. In difference of object type, compiler at compile time will just ignore code that uses it, and generate special runtime object, if there is error, yuo will figure  out it only at runtime (type mismatching for example). More or less like VB 6.0 in good old days (I'm not really aware of VB.NET now)

Comment: In my case it *has* to be `dynamic`. I can remove overloads (I don't want to), but I can't eliminate `dynamic`.

Comment: @Daniel: have a look here: http://www.codethinked.com/overloading-dynamic, doesn't seems to me that it's helpful in this case, but by the way, a useful information.

Comment: @Tigran: Nice article. I would expect my code to at least compile, and, according to this article, even succeed at run-time, given that the return type of `DynamicObject` is `object` at run-time.

Comment: @Daniel: the thing is compiler need "strong key" to find right method. In that article reporter uses pairs (string, dynamic), (dynamic, int). So compiler is able, in his case, to find a best match. In your case it's not clear string or int? I think that is a difference, honestly.

Comment: @Tigran: The article also gives the example of an overload accepting only `dynamic` parameters (end of the article). Passing two `dynamic` variables with run-time types of `object` succeeds. Seems very similar to my scenario.

Comment: @Daniel: sure :) If you change 3rd line of code provided in my post to  static void M(Func<dynamic> f) { }, it will work again. Cause, I THINK, trying to find EXACT matching compiler will say OBJECT can be string? Yes, but is there something more presice? INT can be object, YES, but is there something more presice? dynamic can be OBJECT? It is compiled like an object actually, so pick up that overload.

Comment: @Tigran: The parameters in the article were `dynamic`, just like mine.

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2911/discussion-between-tigran-and-daniel)